# How to create jQuery Element Methods with NameSpace

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Suffice it to say, I'm wanting to branch my plugin writing a bit, and decided I want to be able to "namespace" them. So far, rewriting the `$.method` ones to `$.namespace.method` has been easy.

The problem I'm having is making Element Methods such as `$('element').method()`, but to use a namespace; for example `$('element').namespace.method()`.  I've tried a few workarounds and can create `$.fn.namespace.method`, however, when I call `this` from within that method, I only get `$.fn.namespace` and not the `'element'` that I'd like to get.

Example: If i call `$('body').namespace.test()`, then inside method `test`, I want `this` to be the element `<body></body>`

Any help figuring out how to pull this off much appreciated. Probably just over-thinking things as usual.

Currently trying possible work-arounds for something like `$('body').namespace().method()`, thus far, not working so well ... :P

Comment: +1 - I don't think this is possible in JavaScript. You should just prefix your method names (e.g. `namespaceTest`). If real namespacing is so important to you, then I'm afraid you can't use jQuery's prototype.

Comment: I may be missing your point, but are you just looking for `$.fn.myMethod(/* function code */);` which you then call like `$("div").myMethod()`?

Comment: @JosephSilber It's JavaScript! I'm sure there's a way! LoL, after all, this is the "freest" language out there!

Comment: @Archer No, as I mentioned, I want `$("div").myNameSpace.myMethod();`

Comment: Okay - I was going off the comment `"The problem I'm having is making Element Methods such as $('element').method()"`

Comment: @Archer my bad, language thing i guess, i was using `such as` in terms of "Here's how they do it" | "example kind of thing"

Comment: Yeah, I understand now.  Having a play but not coming up with anything helpful.

Comment: why wont you try to make javascript objects containing the full information about your custom element? infact every dom elements are object. I might be wrong ,corect me as i could understand abt your issue more clearly. Very nice post i must say. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to be compatible with IE8, you may use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Working example :

```
 Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'namespace', {
  get: function(){
    var t = this;
    return {
      lowercasehtml: function(){
         return t.html(function(_,h){ return h.toLowerCase() }); 
      }
    }
  }
});

$('#a').namespace.lowercasehtml(); // changes the html of #a to lowercase (yes, it's stupid, I know)
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ocasud/5/edit)**

But I'm not convinced it's a good idea to namespace like this. I would have simply defined

```
$.fn.namespace_lowercasehtml = function() ...
```

That's what I personally do for my application specific extensions to jQuery.

Comment: nice suggestion, I'll try it right after lunch, any thought on IE8 work around?

Comment: To be honest I think my second suggestion, even if not fancy, is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't recommend it, you can generate a new object for every call to `namespace()`:

```
(function($){

    var plugin = {
        test: function (){
            console.log(this);
        }
    };

    var methods = Object.keys( plugin );

    $.fn.namespace = function (){

        var self = this,
            localMethods = {};

        $.each(methods, function () {
            localMethods[ this ] = plugin[ this ].bind(self);
        });

        return localMethods;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WaXzL/

---

You can either [polyfill `Object.keys` for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility), or just create the `methods` array manually.

Same goes for `bind`: either polyfill it, or `call` it manually.

Here's a version that would work in older browsers:

```
(function($){

    var plugin = {
        test: function (){
            console.log(this);
        }
    };

    var methods = [];

    for ( var i in plugin ) {
        if ( plugin.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
            methods.push(i);
        }
    }

    $.fn.namespace = function (){

        var self = this,
            localMethods = {};

        $.each(methods, function (i, method) {
            localMethods[ method ] = function () {
                plugin[ method ].call( self );
            };
        });

        return localMethods;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WaXzL/1/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added support for passing arguments to any local method: http://jsfiddle.net/WaXzL/2/

Answer (score 2):

How about instead of doing:

```
$('element').namespace.method()
```

you simplify it and do

```
$('element').namespace('method')
```

instead?  This is much simpler:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        test: function(a, b){
            console.log(this, a, b);
        }
    };

    $.fn.namespace = function(method){
        var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return methods[method].apply(this, params);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then you'd do something like: `$('body').namespace('test', 1, 2);`

Comment: because my intellisense in my IDE will read `$('ele').namespace.method()` but it won't read a method name passed as string param

Comment: @SpYk3HH: I was trying to keep it simple.  I don't use a "fancy" IDE.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to just have one main method, and pass the method name as a string:

```
(function($){

    var plugin = {
        test: function (){
            console.log(this);
        },
        otherTest: function (){
            console.log(this);
        }
    };

    $.fn.namespace = function (method){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return plugin[ method ].call(this, args);
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yYNDH/

Comment: @dystroy - Yeah. I had gone over to JSFiddle to create the fiddle before I posted, and when I came back, I didn't realize that he had already posted it.