# How to create jQuery namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create jQuery namespace?

```
$.fn.zyl = {
  foo1 : function(){
   return this.each(function(){
       //...
   })}
}
```

I want to use `$().zyl.foo1()` but `this.each` is not a function.
I'd like to use `$().zyl.foo1()` rather than `$().zyl().foo1()` or `$().zyl('foo1')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create jQuery Element Methods with NameSpace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704130/how-to-create-jquery-element-methods-with-namespace)

Comment: Also possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527089/is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery

Comment: Their answers are `$().zyl().foo1()` or `$().zyl('foo1')`, I want to use `$().zyl.foo1()` and compatible with browsers.